# Heap error when I try to deallocate memory

Tags: c

In my program, I use a 2D-matrice where each cell represents a structure composed of two doubles. At the end of my program, I would like to deallocate all the memory used by this matrice.
So I wrote a double loop "for" like that:

```
if (I != NULL)
{
    for (i = 0; i < nb_prev; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < nb_samples; j++)
        {
            free(&(I[i][j]));
        }
        free(&(I[i]));
    }
}
```

But I obtain a heap error after the second loop inside the seconde "for". Maybe I have done a mistake. Could anyone help me please ?

**Updated from comments:**

The memory is allocated as follows:

```
Power_time **I; 
I = (Power_vtime)malloc(sizeof(Power_time*)*nb_prev); 
if (I == NULL) exit(0); 
for (i = 0; i < nb_prev; i++) { 
    I[i] = (Power_time*)malloc(sizeof(Power_versus_time)*nb_samples); 
    if (I_arriv[i] == NULL) exit(0); 
}
```

Comment: How is `I` declared, and how do you allocate the memory?

Comment: If `I` is an array of structs, not an array of pointers to structs - just do `free(I)` and you're done.

Comment: `code`Power_time **I;
I = (Power_vtime**)malloc(sizeof(Power_time*)*nb_prev);
if (I == NULL)
 exit(0);
for (i = 0; i < nb_prev; i++)
{
 I[i] = (Power_time*)malloc(sizeof(Power_versus_time)*nb_samples);
if (I_arriv[i] == NULL)
 exit(0);
}`code`

Comment: @user2194381 You should add such additional information to your question by editing it - especially code in comments is hard to read. This time, I have added the code to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `I` is a 2D matrix of structs (and not pointers to structs), there shouldn't be an inner loop.

You also need to do `free(I)` at the end.

Basically, how you deallocate memory should be a mirror image of how you've allocated it. You have a single `malloc()` followed by a 1D loop of `malloc()`s. The mirror image is a 1D loop of `free()` followed by a single `free()` at the end.